# How can my app tell if it's running in Chrome vs on an Android device?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

If I use ARCWelder to port my app to Chrome, is there a way for it to know that it's running on Chrome? Maybe through BUILD.Version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect programmatically if "Android App" is running in chrome book or in Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784415/how-to-detect-programmatically-if-android-app-is-running-in-chrome-book-or-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc):

> If you need to check if your app is running on Chrome OS, look for chromium as the android.os.Build.BRAND and android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.

Comment: Thank you - the link is very helpful too

Comment: This was true of the old ARC welder system but no longer works in the current incarnation of ARC.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784415/how-to-detect-programmatically-if-android-app-is-running-in-chrome-book-or-in).

Answer (score 2):

```
//Check for brand and manufacturer
if(Build.BRAND.equals("chromium") && Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("chromium")){
      /*Code to be executed if app is running on chromium*/
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please expand a bit on your answer. It's pretty much self-explanatory in this case, but code-only answers are generally not acceptable :)