# How to detect programmatically if "Android App" is running in chrome book or in Android phone

Tags: android, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

Since Google has announced that chromebook also support "Android Application" so I also wanted to support my app on chromebook although it is running fine with few exception which I need to fix.

I want to write code in such a way that that is will execute only for chromebook and will not execute for android phones and tablet.

I have check with Chromebook documentation in android developer site, I didn't get any such API which tell that your app is running in chrome book environment.

---

Suggestion from [ARC Beta documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) did not work:

> If you need to check if your app is running on Chrome OS, look for *chromium* as the `android.os.Build.BRAND` and `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`.

Both return *google* on an ASUS Chromebook.

Comment: Done; there is apparently a tag already. I deleted my answer and edited what was tried there into the question. Good luck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally I figure out a way to know if app in running in ARC:

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management");
```

Comment: Can anybody using a chromebook actually confirm this? Are you sure that the final native integration from Android apps into chromebook will use the ARC in the same way?

Comment: @TSGames Yes, I have confirmed it and it is working as expected. Device used : Google Pixel Chromebook

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it in Haier E11 Chromebook and also works :)

Comment: @Gabor Yes It is working on older pixel that I have. I am not sure about the new Google pixel chromebook that Google has recently launched.

Comment: I am using chrome os with Kiosks mode and I have applied all code above, but not able find it is crome box or not. please help me out. I need to open in-app keyboard for chrome os kiosk mode. note:- I am not using ARC Welder

Comment: Is there any way to check the same thing on flutter

Comment: Thanks! I've checked it in Lenovo Flex11 Chromebook and it working (Y)

Comment: How to indicated that chromebook is in tablet mode (flipped). Because it seems that chromebook in tablet mode behaves like a regular tablet

Comment: See the Jan 15, 2023 change to my answer above for a 2nd system feature that Google checks besides the device_management string ...and a quick kotlin replacement.  (I chased down the source code to see where the isArc() function had gone off to, and this is what I found)

Answer (score 9):

**2023 Note**-- Jump to the bottom of this answer to read the latest way Android identifies a Chromebook/Desktop/PC device, including a new test from within the Android emulator.  Or, keep reading below for the full, exciting history of the ARC check and how Google has changed their own method several times.

**Older:**

A method [Google uses in their own code](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/android/marvin/talkback/TalkBackService.java#L1779-L1781) (updated several times now from [link](https://github.com/google/talkback/blame/9b1d5132b074174d02886faccf731e814d69363c/utils/src/main/java/FeatureSupport.java)) is to check if `Build.DEVICE` ends with "`_cheets`".  I don't know if ending device names like this is some kind of long-term strategy or a fast workaround, but it's also worth a look in addition to dex's proposed solution.

FWIW, since ARCWelder's method is deprecated and there's no official documentation on this (yet), I've also [started a discussion](https://forum.xda-developers.com/hardware-hacking/chromebooks/apk-running-chromeos-arc-how-to-tell-t3630599/post72878797) in the XDA forums here for people to discuss what works/doesn't work on various devices.

**Update 5/18:**  Looks like the code above was moved and updated, so Google's new ARC check as of May 2018 is [here](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/e69d4731fce02bb9e69613d0e48c29033cad4a98/utils/src/main/java/FormFactorUtils.java#L42), particularly in this bit:

```
... } else if (Build.DEVICE != null && Build.DEVICE.matches(ARC_DEVICE_PATTERN)) {
  mFormFactor = FORM_FACTOR_ARC;
} else { ...
```

where `ARC_DEVICE_PATTERN` is [defined](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/e69d4731fce02bb9e69613d0e48c29033cad4a98/utils/src/main/java/FormFactorUtils.java#L35) as

```
private static final String ARC_DEVICE_PATTERN = ".+_cheets|cheets_.+";
```

So it's not just a device ending with `_cheets`.  It can start with `cheets_` as well.

**Update 8/26/20** -- As of 7 months ago, the source has been moved around from `FormFactors.java` to `FeatureSupport.java`.  If you were looking for where it went- [here it the code as of today](https://github.com/google/talkback/blame/9b1d5132b074174d02886faccf731e814d69363c/utils/src/main/java/FeatureSupport.java).

```
  public static boolean isArc() {
    return (Build.DEVICE != null && Build.DEVICE.matches(".+_cheets|cheets_.+"));
  }
```

The test remains the same.

**Jan 15, 2023** -- The code has changed again!  `isArc()` is now built into the **FeatureUtil** class (see commit [here](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/cts/+/9a31819d57f6a6df70ca90f0e126ff40bf086d43:common/device-side/util-axt/src/com/android/compatibility/common/util/FeatureUtil.java;dlc=4ea580d07d6c7f9940c236d1413c4cef432709a8)) The current version of `isArc()` :

```
/** Returns {@code true} if device is an ARC++ device. */
    public static boolean isArc() {
        return hasAnySystemFeature(ARC_FEATURE, ARC_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT_FEATURE);
    }
```

Where `ARC_FEATURE` and `ARC_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT_FEATURE` are defined like this:

```
public static final String ARC_FEATURE = "org.chromium.arc";
public static final String ARC_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT_FEATURE = "org.chromium.arc.device_management";
```

the function [hasAnySystemFeature()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/common/device-side/util-axt/src/com/android/compatibility/common/util/FeatureUtil.java;drc=35e28d5a0f81b3cb2059f048ac99ce56f1fa1463;l=51) simply checks individual features and returns true if any is true.

Therefore the following might work as a simple standalone check in kotlin (where `context` is the activity context):

```
   fun isArc(): Boolean {
        return ((context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc")) || (context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management")))
```

Note this is similar to @dex's answer below, but includes *both* tests used by the Android source.

Incidentally, from looking at the code linked above you can also check other device characteristics like like `isWatch()`, `isTV()`, `isAutomotive()`, `isPC()`, `isVrHeadset()`, `isLowRam()`, etc. using similar feature checks.

**June 30, 2023** - [hasAnySystemFeature()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/common/device-side/util-axt/src/com/android/compatibility/common/util/FeatureUtil.java;drc=35e28d5a0f81b3cb2059f048ac99ce56f1fa1463;l=51) doesn't seem to work in recent ChromeOS/Desktop emulator images (such as the Sv2 - Android 12L API 34 (desktop) image). However, it looks like you can detect this in the Android Emulator by checking for the device model info found in `ro.product.model` From the `adb shell`, use `$ getprop | grep ro.product.model` to see a line like:

```
 [ro.product.model]: [sdk_gpc_x86_64]
```

The "gpc" sugggests Google PC (There exists also a `sdk_gphone64_x86_64` as a matter of comparison), and hints in [code elsewhere](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/test_util.cpp#85) suggest this may be a new convention.  So in Kotlin, if you're looking for ChromeOS in the emulator, try adding this to the [hasAnySystemFeature()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/common/device-side/util-axt/src/com/android/compatibility/common/util/FeatureUtil.java;drc=35e28d5a0f81b3cb2059f048ac99ce56f1fa1463;l=51) check above:

```kotlin
// is the emulator running a desktop/ChromeOS image?
if (Build.MODEL != null && Build.MODEL.startsWith("sdk_gpc_")) {
   // it probably is (?)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same think on flutter

Comment: How to indicated that chromebook is in tablet mode (flipped). Because it seems that chromebook in tablet mode behaves like a regular tablet

Answer (score 2):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PC)) 
   // it's a chromebook
```

Comment: "Official" way is outdated. For latest Pixelbook for instance brand is "google"

Comment: FEATURE_PC is not find with PackageManager

Comment: @uday-nayak with which Chromebook did you try and what Android OS version does it run?

Comment: You may need to follow https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/input-compatibility#use_androidhardwaretypepc

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in [Android CTS code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android12-release/common/device-side/util-axt/src/com/android/compatibility/common/util/FeatureUtil.java#82).

```
public static boolean isArc(@NonNull Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature( "org.chromium.arc" ) || pm.hasSystemFeature( "org.chromium.arc.device_management" );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).