# Is there a way to prevent an Android app to be installed on Chrome OS?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os

Some users are installing an Android app I've worked on in their Chromebooks. The app is not working properly and the users are blaming the app instead of the fact that Android support in their Chromebooks is still in beta.

Is there a parameter in the manifest or configuration in Play Store to prevent an Android app to be installed in Chrome OS?

This is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784415/how-to-detect-programmatically-if-android-app-is-running-in-chrome-book-or-in). I want to prevent installation, not detecting Chrome OS once it is already running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect programmatically if "Android App" is running in chrome book or in Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784415/how-to-detect-programmatically-if-android-app-is-running-in-chrome-book-or-in)

Comment: Android support for Chromebooks is in the stable channel and no longer in beta. It is very much your app that is broken at this point.

Comment: That is incorrect @ianhanniballake as you can see it depends on the device https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps

Comment: @MartinMarconcini it is not a duplicate since I want to prevent installation, not detect Chrome OS once it's already running.

Comment: @Pier - oh, and your app **only** doesn't work on devices in the beta channel? And you've confirmed that they work on every Chromebook on the stable channel? And you've [filed a bug against Chrome](www.crbug.com) for each specific device that your app doesn't work on?

Comment: @ianhanniballake My app doesn't crash. The web view is acting erratically. Yes my users have only one model since this is a school and all users have the same model. You are assuming too many things.

Comment: There is nothing in the manifest that you can specify that bans Chrome OS devices uniquely. Certain `<uses-feature>` elements, such as one for `android.software.app_widget`, may have the effect of banning your app from Chrome OS devices, but it may ban your app from other devices as well.

Comment: Until the play store offers the option, I guess you’re out of luck :/

Answer (score 0):

My app wasn't available on Chromebook by accident. To find out why I turned on the Chrome OS lint in Android Studio. It's in preferences->editor->inspections.

After turning it on an error showed up in AndroidManifest.xml on this line:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Apparently I had to add some uses-feature tags. So see if you can find something that causes an error *only* when the Chrome OS lint is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Play Console supported device list to manually exclude any Chromebook type devices. This would be something you'd need to check before every new release, to see if any new Chromebook devices were listed.

In Google Play Console, go to "Device catalog" under your app in question then click "Manage devices" then select "Exclude devices" from the drop down menu.
Use the "Form factor" filter, to find all devices of "Chromebook" type and mark them as excluded.

This way your app should not appear in Google Play on selected Chromebook devices.