# Chromebook specification through Android app

Tags: android, specifications, chromebook

Simply, **android.os.Build.MODEL** information and others on Chromebook is needed.

I am managing 3rd party library which is used for several published games, with totally not considered run on Chromebook.

Some of my customers asked me to want to know my library's Chromebook compatibility because they are getting some CS from there end-users.
I don't have Chromebook now, but My library reports some data to monitor crash or ANR, etc.

I could not find any device information from which can specify the log came from Chrome OS or Chromebook devices which listed on Google`s Chromebook list. (https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps)

Anyone can share with me what kinds of device model information and OS version is shown when the Android app launched on Chromebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:
[How to detect programmatically if "Android App" is running in chrome book or in Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784415/how-to-detect-programmatically-if-android-app-is-running-in-chrome-book-or-in)

> context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management");